# Typescript: Why does undefined as unknown as string result in undefined?

Tags: typescript

I had the impression that a type assertion to string would result in a previously-unknown type to turn into a string. I appreciate some explanation as to why this is not the case.

```
$npx ts-node
> undefined as string
[eval].ts:1:1 - error TS2352: Conversion of type 'undefined' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> undefined as unknown as string
undefined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [docs on type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html):

> Type Assertion vs. Casting
>
> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However, type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

This means, `foo as string` will cause TypeScript compiler to *treat* `foo` as a string, even if it *is not* one. Specifically, `undefined` doesn't magically turn into not-`undefined` by TS compiler thinking it's a string.

However, TypeScript also knows that very few things that are not strings can be treated as a string sensibly, so you get an error (unless you trick it into forgetting what it was first).